# Why Can't a MappedByteBuffer Expand?

Tags: java, io, buffer

With regards to [Expanding Java Memory-Mapped Byte Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028522/expanding-java-memory-mapped-byte-buffer), why doesn't the buffer expand upon writing past the limit? There isn't even a way to implement the behavior apparently without remapping the buffer. This also seems somewhat strange to me because I'd imagine that a few developers have wanted it, or is this just using the buffer in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `MappedByteBuffer` is a `ByteBuffer` is a `Buffer`, which has a fixed capacity defined on creation. So the semantics of `Buffer` prevent it.

As @SotiriosDelimanolis and @fge mention, the operating system semantics also prevent it. The memory mapping is created with a fixed size, and if you address beyond that size at the native level you will get a `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: Does the concept of a memory-mapped file also prevent it? For example, what would it mean to the OS for a process to try and write bytes past the memory allocated for the mmap?